# Position change while zoom in

Tags: javascript, html, css, zooming

Here I tried to make simple zoom in and out functions on button click.

**HTML**

```
 <input type="button" value ="-" onClick="zoom(0.9)"/>
 <input type="button" value ="+" onClick="zoom(1.1)"/>
 <div id="thediv">

 <img id="pic" src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/VistaICO_Toolbar-Icons/256/Zoom-in.png"/>
 </div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
var zoomLevel = 100;
var maxZoomLevel = 105;
var minZoomLevel = 95;

function zoom(zm) {
var img=document.getElementById("pic");
if(zm > 1){
    if(zoomLevel < maxZoomLevel){
        zoomLevel++;
    }else{
        return;
    }
}else if(zm < 1){
    if(zoomLevel > minZoomLevel){
        zoomLevel--;
    }else{
        return;
    }
}
wid = img.width;
ht = img.height;
img.style.width = (wid*zm)+"px";
img.style.height = (ht*zm)+"px";
img.style.marginLeft = -(img.width/2) + "px";
img.style.marginTop = -(img.height/2) + "px";
}
```

But the problem is, whenever I click the zoom-in function the image moves to the top corner of the page. I tried to solve this but no solution was effective.

Here is the [BIN](http://jsbin.com/itekek/2/) I am working on which may be useful to find my mistake.

And also another question: Is there a way to apply mousewheel to this function?

**UPDATE**

The problem of zoom has been changed. But now the mousewheel also done here but the problem is we can't give the maximum value for the mousewheel.
[UPDATED BIN](http://jsbin.com/itekek/48/)

Answer (score 2):

```
img.style.marginLeft = -(img.width/2) + "px"; // you have negation sign here
img.style.marginTop = -(img.height/2) + "px"; // you have negation sign here
```

Change it TO :

```
img.style.marginLeft = (img.width/2) + "px";
img.style.marginTop = (img.height/2) + "px";
```

[JS BIN LINK](http://jsbin.com/itekek/5)

Answer (score 1):

Judging by your `marginLeft` and `marginTop` calculation, I guess that you want to zoom in and out of the image while preserving the center point.

So try this:

http://jsbin.com/itekek/4

Preserved an initial width and height value, and slightly modified the zoom limit value.

**Edit**:

http://jsbin.com/itekek/46

Added mouse wheel support.

Comment: +1 Its what i needed But i have to implement mousewheeling too

Comment: @VivekDragon Added mouse wheel support. Noted that up until now, mouse wheel support amount different browsers are quite not-that-standard. I made it base on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536951%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [MDN](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/en-US/DOM/DOM_event_reference/DOMMouseScroll).

Comment: Is there any way to change that document.getElementById("") to get a class there....

Comment: @VivekDragon I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but if you want to select an element by its class name, use [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.querySelector). Doesn't work on IE<8 though.

Answer (score 1):

See this : http://jsbin.com/itekek/14/edit

You have unstripped zoom plus Mousewheel here..

**Update**: To get elements by class name use function below:

```
function findElementByClass(matchClass) {
 var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('*'),i;
 for (i in elems) {
    if ((" " + elems[i].className + " ").indexOf(" " + matchClass + " ") > -1) {
        return elems[i];
    }
   }
  return null;
}
```

See [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/2MHsL/)

Comment: Its working fine but the problem here is its mousewheel value also set to be fixed like the buttons

Comment: +1 i read the code there is a value  zooming.min=min || 50;  Is there any possibility to make another maximum value diclaration for this

Comment: Thanks A.V thats way cool is there any way to change that document.getElementById("") to get a class there....